# 2 Column Layout with Image and Text (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Hey I want to achieve a 2 column layout, where I have a row with an image and an text like this:
http://prntscr.com/plrpcf

I already have a 2 col layout for buttons but I gues i need to wrap the image and text in another layoutcontainer

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:src="@drawable/1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"

            android:text="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:src="@drawable/2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"

            android:text="2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I got it working somehow with the above script, but the images are really small, they dont stretch to the full size of the parent, any ideas

Actually they do stretch if I have a static source for the images. When I load them via script they get smaller

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tex4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="qweqweqwqweqwe" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img5"

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tex5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="asdasdasasasdasd" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

Use `adjustviewBounds = true` on the images and it will stretch the images!